# How to copy textbox value into another textbox in MVC3 razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i want to copy city1 textbox value to city2 textbox using javascript.

### My javascript code--

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
$("#chkCopy").change(function() {
    $("#city1").val("");
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#city2").val($("#city1").val())
    }

});

});​ 
</script>
```

### my view-

```
@Html.TextBox("city1", "abc")
@Html.TextBox("city2")
@Html.CheckBox("check", new { id = "chkCopy" })
```

This is just a demo i need to implement this one in my project.Plzz help me.

Comment: You want to copy city1's value to city2 and you are assigining address1's value.

Comment: ohh...syntax error but still not working.

Comment: Did it help you?Is it working for you now?

Comment: did you try looking at the demo link I gave.

Answer (score 0):

**[Check the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vQhhR/)**.

I think on change of your `checkbox` you are clearing the value of `city1` `textbox` and hence it is not working for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not clearing the value of city1.I dont know what is the problem.I think this code is correct.

Comment: @ghihi Post your updated code.Did you try to do a simple alert to check if the function is being called.Post the code you now have.

Comment: @ghihi This is jquery only.please post the latest code , what is the exact problem let me know,this should be some simple thing that you might be missing.